# Does the learning rate reset when I stop training in jupyter? Tensorflow.Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Does the learning rate reset when I stop training in jupyter?
 I said during training to lower it by * 0.1 when my model starts to stagnate.
If I stop training and then restart it right after, does that reset the learning rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ideally it will restart again if you are not initializing with new value.

This of this as a function which is stopped and rerun again. If you don't write the custom logic to restart again from the old LR it will continue from its initialized value which is the begging again.

Comment: Yes after verification, I have the learning rate unchanged. That's it, thank you very much